# Stata: How to use scalars in variable indexes

Tags: loops, syntax-error, stata

I would like to use a loop scalar in a variable index. Sample code:

```
forvalues j = 1(1)9 {

gen cname_year`j' = CNAME if acyear == `j'

if `j' > 1 {
scalar endv = `j' - 1
forvalues k = 1(1)`endv' {

replace cname_year`j' = cname_year`j'[_n+`k'] if acyear[_n+`k'] == `j' & ID[_n] == ID[_n+`k']

}
}
}
```

The following line gives me a "syntax error":

```
replace cname_year`j' = cname_year`j'[_n+`k'] if acyear[_n+`k'] == `j' & ID[_n] == ID[_n+`k']
```

Not sure how to fix this. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use a `scalar` here, but if you do you certainly need a different syntax. Try instead

```
local endv = `j' - 1
```

The larger code example seems to be working with panel data in a moderately awkward way. If you run into further problems with that, you might need to come back to the forum, but we would need much more context to be clear on what is being attempted.

If you were to use a scalar, then the syntax would be

```
forvalues k = 1(1)`= endv'
```

or (arguably more explicit and so better style) given that `endv` could be a variable name

```
forvalues k = 1(1)`= scalar(endv)'
```

The syntax you used is designed for local macros, and so requires one to be defined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So it looks like perhaps the error was being generated by the forvalues expression and not by the line I highlighted. I will try your suggestion and report back.

Comment: To give some more context on what I am trying to do, basically I am trying to find an efficient way to collapse a data set with some string variables. The only "collapse" operators that work with strings are "first" and "last"-- "firstnm" and "lastnm" only work with numeric variables. So basically I am trying to copy the values of the string variables back to the first position for their cluster so I can catch them with the "first" operator of the "collapse" command.

Comment: Typically string variables appear in the `by()` option of `collapse`. What would the reduction look like otherwise?